# style.display ='inline not working in IE but its working fine FireFox

Tags: css

Hi we are have a strange issue.

One of our clients is complaining, that in IE they are unable to see any value , when they select a value from the drop down.

The strange thing is , its working in fire Fox.Also we could not even replicate in IE on our end.

the code that gets executed in java script when a value is selected in a drop down

```
document.getElementById('GLSpan').innerHTML = pnumArr[0];
document.getElementById('GLCheckbox').style.display ='inline';
```

GLSpan is a span element
GLCheckbox is a check box element

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Which IE version? Did you test in the same version as the client used?

Comment: No such thing as a "check box element" - I take it you mean an `<input type="checkbox">`?

Comment: ya I thought it would be obvious to consider "check box element" as <input type="checkbox">,but I guess I should have mentioned that.The versions they are using is IE 7 or IE8..and we have tried but could not replicate the error

Comment: I am also having a problem with style.display=""/"inline"/"block" in IE8 and below, it's a strange one, but I do think it's a genuine issue. Would like to know if anyone has a solution

Answer (score 0):

Wow they **couldn't** be on ie 4 could they? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751(VS.85).aspx

If so you might want to gently suggest they upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english ...

try with "block" or "" value for style.display, I am not sure but I think checkbox doesn't have attribute "inline" for display property for IE

Comment: but check box do have style atttribute rt?and its working perfectly in FF and its even working great in IE on our end..its only the problem from client's side

Comment: IE Versions? if you have the same version than your client, likely you client (or you) has some plugin, add-on or something like installed, try reproduce the error on other machine than you client or yours.